# Apache proxy/redirect to Tomcat works from 80 to 8080 but not from 443 to 8443

Tags: apache, tomcat8

In my Apache configuration I have two virtual server setups, one for 80 and one for 443. My VirtualHost *:80 config successfully proxies/redirects a path to tomcat 8080, but my analogously configured VirtualHost *:443 config is not proxying to the required tomcat 8443.

I have checked the Connector in tomcat and can successfully hit the tomcat endpoints directly over 8443. I can also hit other parts of the web-server over 443, just not any of the app-server endpoints that require the proxy/redirect. So, I know that the certs and tomcat configs are working.

Apache and Tomcat are running on the same ec2 server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cloviscorp.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/com/cloviscorp
    <Directory "/var/www/html/com/cloviscorp">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /ClovisWebApp http://localhost:8080/ClovisWebApp
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    ... (CORS config and LOG setup) ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName cloviscorp.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/com/cloviscorp
    <Directory "/var/www/html/com/cloviscorp">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /ClovisWebApp https://localhost:8443/ClovisWebApp
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/server.key"

    ... (CORS config and LOG setup) ...
</VirtualHost>
```

When hitting http://www.cloviscorp.com/ClovisWebApp/authenticationservice/login I correctly proxy to http://www.cloviscorp.com:8080/ClovisWebApp/authenticationservice/login, but when I hit https://www.cloviscorp.com/ClovisWebApp/authenticationservice/login I get `The requested URL /ClovisWebApp/authenticationservice/login was not found on this server.`

Comment: First ensure `https://localhost:8443/ClovisWebApp` does work.  Then put your logs in debug mode and try again.  It is possible your certificate is rejected.  You might have to add directives to ignore certificate validation.

Comment: https://localhost:8443/ClovisWebApp endpoints work fine when hit directly. Logs are not showing anything. My problem seems to be on the apache side.

Comment: should i install mod_jk and go that route?

Comment: From various logs, in DEBUG mode:
```[info] mod_ssl/2.2.34 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.34, Library: OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
[notice] Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.3.29 configured -- resuming normal operations```
...
```[debug] proxy_util.c(1951): proxy: worker https://localhost:8443/ClovisWebApp already initialized```
...
```[debug] proxy_util.c(1951): proxy: worker http://localhost:8080/ClovisWebApp already initialized```
...